# How to fix the sound issue in 18.04

Tags: sound, speakers

[image: sound issue - player works properly]

I  have sound issue in 18.04. I was installed 18.04 four months before, at that time no issue with sound, but yesterday i was connect to HDMI projector, after that the system speaker or external speaker having no sound when the player is working. Solution please

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after not installing third party software and update in the first installation step in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
You should just shift from gdm3 to lightdm to resolve this issue by opening the terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

After entering these commands if you are asked that only one of gdm3 or lightdm ubuntu can use then simply select lightdm when asked.
This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be that the sound driver is not installed. You'll need to check with your manufacturer about what sound card is in your device to find the correct driver, but you can try with the Intel Sound Driver (which is a common one) by running

`sudo apt install firmware-intel-sound`

You could also try enabling the Pulseaudio sound service if it is disabled by running

`pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog`

(If it is disabled by default, you'll have to re-enter it every time the system reboots (or add it to the startup services with the "Startup Applications" program)).
The Pulseaudio volume control program lets you manage the sound with a graphical frontend.

Install it with

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

You can try re-installing the core sound packages with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio linux-sound-base libasound2
```

If all of that fails, try killing the service with

`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*`, followed by a reboot.

Comment: Issue fixed in my system using these commands

Comment: Then you don't use Ubuntu as the package `firmware-intel-sound` does not exist in Ubuntu.