# Audio devices not appearing

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Ubuntu Gnome 18.04.

None of my audio devices (S/PDIF interfaces, HDMI, or USB Kingston HyperX headphones) appear in the sound panel, of my fresh install.

I've used MANY distros, including this Ubuntu 18.04, with the same headphones on the same machine, over the past few years, and have never had this issue.

I found [this article](https://zillowtech.com/ubuntu-no-sound.html) and it said to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base

sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base

sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```

> Then reboot

THIS WORKS, but after rebooting it's missing all of the devices again. I tried everything else in that article as well.

I also tried removing the folder:

```
~.config/Pulse
```

and rebooting to have the system rebuild it, but it doesn't work either. The contents of that folder are as follows:

- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-card-database.tdb
- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-default-sink
- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-default-source
- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-device-volumes.tdb
- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-runtime
- 52d08a3291ab4c5a90ad1f14948aeb7a-stream-volumes.tdb
- cookie

Here is my 
     lspci -k

output: https://hastebin.com/raw/supidakiro  (pastebin is down for me right now)

Not sure what other info to provide. Let me know and I'll try to give more info.

---

## **EDIT:**

Those commands from the article no longer work, even temporarily anymore. I found [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163757/how-to-fix-the-sound-issue-in-18-04) and did this command:

```
pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

and it immediately fixes it. So how can I make this happen automatically at boot? I'd still like to know how this was broken too, since I've never had this issue before....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a new startup command to "startup applications" with the following on the command line:

```
pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

rebooted and now pulseaudio starts as it should.

I'm still curious as to why this broke in the first place. This is a fresh install...

EDIT: from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962920/how-do-i-get-pulseaudio-to-start-automatically-in-ubuntu-17-04-and-17-10-for-fir) I did the following:

```
cp -p /etc/pulse/client.conf ~/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

and now my audio works even after rebooting.